# Merge two binary columns into one keep the binary option

Tags: r

Inserting as input this dataframe:

```
data.frame(stocknum = c(1,2,3), text = c(1,0,1), final = c(0,0,1))
```

How is it possible to merge the two columns text and final into one keep the binary option, example  output

```
data.frame(stocknum = c(1,2,3), text = c(1,0,1), final = c(0,0,1), merged_text_final = c(1,0,1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pmax` from `base R`

```
df1$merged_text_final <- with(df1, pmax(text, final))
```

---

Or another option is `|` with `Reduce`

```
df1$merged_text_final <- +(Reduce(`|`, df1[c("text", "final")]))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(stocknum = c(1,2,3), text = c(1,0,1), final = c(0,0,1))
```

Comment: @rek The first option can be generalized i.e. `do.call(pmax, df1[-1])` just like the second with `Reduce`

Comment: @rek you can specify the names as a vector i.e `df1[c("text", "final")]` updated or with numeric index `df1[2:3]`

Comment: @rek Did to meant to reverse the 1->0 and 0->1, then you can do `+(!do.call(pmax, df[c("text", "final")]))`

Answer (score 2):

Using `any`.

```
+apply(d[-1], 1, any)
# [1] 1 0 1
```

Throws a warning, but we know why, and may do `suppressWarnings(+apply(d[-1], 1, any))`

Another option, `rowMeans`.

```
+(rowMeans(d[-1])>0)
# [1] 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option

```
transform(
  df,
  merged_text_final = +(rowSums(cbind(text, final)) > 0)
)
```

gives

```
  stocknum text final merged_text_final
1        1    1     0                 1
2        2    0     0                 0
3        3    1     1                 1
```

---

A `data.table` option

```
setDT(df)[, merged_text_final := +(rowSums(.SD) > 0), .SDcols = c("text", "final")]
```

gives

```
> df
   stocknum text final merged_text_final
1:        1    1     0                 1
2:        2    0     0                 0
3:        3    1     1                 1
```